# Notation for the set of all arguments corresponding to local minima.

Tags: calculus, optimization, notation

The notation $$\mathop{\mathrm{arg\, min}}_{x \in X} f(x)$$
is sometimes used for the set of all $x \in X$ corresponding to **global** minima of the function $x \in X \mapsto f(x).$ Is there notation for the set of all $x \in X$ corresponding to **local** minima? (I included 'calculus' in the tags because it seems likely that someone within that knowledge base knows the answer.)

Comment: Maybe it's not what you want, but I think usually we will just write $x \in \{ x: \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t. } f(x) \leq f(y) \forall y\in(x-\delta, x+\delta)\}$

Comment: I want to argue for Surb's suggestion of putting "$x$ is a local minimum" in text, and against most of the other answers to the question.  Everyone who will read what you're writing knows what a local minimum is, but it takes a little time to parse something like 

$\{x : \exists U \text{ open s.t.} \forall y \in U f(x) \leq f(y)\}$.  There's no need to put everything in symbols.

If you use this set more than once introduce something like, "Let $MINS(f)$ denote the local minima of the function $f$."  That's all you need to say.

Answer (score 4):

I would write as
$$\{x\in X:x=\mathop{\arg\min}_{y\in U^\circ,\ U\subset X}f(y)\}$$
where $U^\circ$ is the interior of $U$, hence open.

Comment: Comment to the OP : I have done a few things in optimization, but I have never seen actual interest in the set you want to consider, which probably explains the lack of popular notation. This answer probably gives you the most compact answer you can get with the state of the language at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

My goal here is to extend the idea proposed by Liu Gang. You could write
$$S:=\{x \in X: x\text{ satisfy property } P\},$$ 
where $P$ is a property that characterizes local minima. Liu Gang chose $P$ to be the mathematical definition of a local minimum. You could also make it even easier by putting $P$ to be the property "is a local minimum", which would then be

$$S:=\{x \in X: x\text{ is a local minimum of } f\}.$$

Nevertheless you could also use more context. For example if $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth then you could write
$$S:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } f'(x) = f''(x)=\ldots = f^{(2n-1)}(x)=0 \text{ and } f^{(2n)}(x) >0\}.$$
Conclusion: through all my readings, I never encountered a symbol that seems to be generally accepted to denote the set of local minima. But it's up to you to propose one and use it in a text that will be THE reference ;).

Answer (score 0):

Considering only the local minima does not seem particularly natural and it is unlikely that there is a standard piece of notation for it. On the other hand, the set of all extrema can be written simply as the level set of the derivative: $\{f'=0\}$.

Comment: Not every function has a derivative. Anyway, why do you argue that considering only local minima does not seem very natural? If you want to know where your numerical minimization algorithm is going to get trapped, you'll want to know the arguments corresponding to local minima.

Comment: That's true, but to find the minima you are going to have to start by finding the extrema anyway :-) On the other hand, if you are dealing with nonsmooth functions then my notation does not help too much.

Answer (score 0):

Like wrote Liu Gang in the comment, using a compact notation for neighborhood such as for example:

$$ f(\bar{x}) \le f(x) \quad \forall x \in U(\bar{x}) $$

Or also:
$$ \bar{x} = \mathop{\mathrm{arg\, min}}_{x \in U(\bar{x})} f(x)  $$
where $U(\bar{x}) \in \mathcal{J}(\bar{x})$, a neighborhood of $\bar{x}$.

I never saw more compact notation